# Validation not work Integrating CAPTCHA

Tags: php, validation, captcha

can somebody help me out and guide me to the right path

I have a simple form and a validation but I got always spam in my email, then I decide to put CAPTCHA into it to stop robot sending spam message.

the problem is even the captcha is blank the message still send to my email, it hard for me to point out what the problem is, because I'm still in learning process in PHP in short I have only basic knowledge in PHP

by the way this is my code:

**HTML**:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    <div class="inputFields">
    <!-- <legend>Comment Form</legend> -->
        <p>
            <label for="name">Name</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name"  <?php if(isset($name)){ echo 'value="' . $name . '" />';} else { echo 'value="" />';} ?>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="email">Email </label><br />
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" <?php if(isset($email)){ echo 'value="' . $email . '" />';} else { echo 'value="" />';} ?>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="location">Location</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="location" id="location" <?php if(isset($location)){ echo 'value="' . $location . '" />';} else { echo 'value="" />';} ?>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label class="yourMessage" for="comment">Your message</label><br />
            <textarea cols="30" rows="10" name="message" id="comment"><?php if(isset($message)){ echo $message;}?></textarea>
        </p>


        <p>
            <label class="captcha" for="captcha">Enter text from image</label><br />
            <img src="test/seccode.php" width="100" height="36" alt="" /><br /><br />
            <input type="text" name="captcha" value="" id="captcha"/>
        </p>



    </div>
    <p>
        <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

**validation**

```
<?php
$submit = htmlentities($_POST['submit']);
$name = htmlentities($_POST['name']);
$email = htmlentities($_POST['email']);
$message = htmlentities($_POST['message']);

if($submit == 'Submit') {

    ###### Validate 'name' and combat Magic Quotes if necessary

    if(isset($name) && !empty($name)) {
        $name2 = stripslashes($name);
        $nameCheck = strlen($name2);
    } else {
        $err_name = '<span>Please enter your <strong>name</strong>.</span>';
        $isError=true;
    }

    ### check if data has numbers

    if(is_numeric($name) ) {
        $err_name = '<span>Please enter a valid <strong>name</strong>. No numbers please.</span>';
        $isError=true;
    }

    if($_POST['captcha'] != $_SESSION['secCode']) {
        // wrong security code
        $err_captcha = '<span><strong>WRONG CODE!</strong></span>';
        $isError=true;
    }
    else {
        // security code is valid; reset it!
        $_SESSION['secCode'] = rand(100000, 999999);
    }


    ###### Validate 'email' and combat Magic Quotes if necessary

    if(!empty($email) && eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $_POST['email'])) {
    } else {
        $err_email = '<span>Please enter a valid <strong>email address</strong>.</span>';
        $isError=true;
    }

    ###### Validate 'message' and combat Magic Quotes if necessary

    if(!empty($message)) {
        $message2 = stripslashes($message);
        $messageCheck = strlen($message2);
    } else {
        $err_message = '<span>Please enter your <strong>message</strong>.</span>';
        $isError=true;
    }


    ###### Mailing Address

    $to  = 'myemail@gmail.com';

    $headers="From: $email\n";

    ###### Body of the email to be sent:

    $message1="Name: $name\nEmail: $email\n\nMessage: $message";

    //$message2="$name \'s message:\n\n\"$message\"";


    ###### Mailing the data

    //!!!!!!!!!!! UNCOMMENT MAIL BELOW WHEN UPLOADED TO WEB HOST !!!!!!!!!!!

    if(!isset($isError)) {

        if(!empty($message)) {
            mail($to,"Message from www.myemail.com",$message1,$headers);
        } else {
            //echo 'fail';
            $err_message = '<font color="red">Please enter your message.</font>';
            $isError=true;
        }
    }


    ###### Forwarding to another page

    if(!empty($isError)) {
    } else {
        header("Location: thank_you.php");
    }
}



?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting.?

Comment: my problem is even the captcha field is empty still message send to my email.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct, event though you can try like below for if condition

```
if($isError) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable $isError is a boolean. So you dont have to check it with !isset():

```
if($isError) {
   // error occured
} else {
  // send your message here
}
```

So try

```
if(!$isError) {

    if(!empty($message)) {
        mail($to,"Message from www.myemail.com",$message1,$headers);

        header("Location: thank_you.php");
    } else {
        //echo 'fail';
        $err_message = '<font color="red">Please enter your message.</font>';
        $isError=true;
    }
}

###### Forwarding to another page

/*if(!$isError) {
   header("Location: thank_you.php");  
}*/
```

Comment: Set your $isError variable at the beginning of your script to false (after <?php insert $isError=false;). Else you get a php error.

Comment: thank you for your answers but still message send to my email even the captcha field is empty